# Somar mm:ss de uma coluna em jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Boa tarde, sei que da forma que irei explicar é complicado me ajudarem.

Tenho uma jTable que contem uma coluna onde são mostrado tempos, esses tempos em mm:ss. Eu preciso calcular a média entre esses tempos. Eu realizei diversas tentativas com alternativas diferentes para conseguir chegar no objetivo porém não consigo ao menos pensar uma **forma** de realizar esse calculo.

**Minha dificuldade:**
Temos os valores dentro da colum da jtable, logo, esses valores são Strings.

**O que eu tentei:**

1. Tentei criar um conversor para mm:ss com SimpleDateFormat e
   armazenar as informações em um vetor, onde apos isso tentaria somar
   as datas.

**Resultado:** uma bos**, não consegui somar da forma que imaginei que conseguiria pois por mais que estava utilizando SimpleDateFormat com mm:ss ele me retornou Thu Jan 01 00:00:10 BRT 1970.

**Unica parte aproveitavel do meu código:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
        tempo_chegada = table.getValueAt(i, 5).toString();
    }
```

[image: Column da jtable]

Não consigo pensar uma lógica de como irei somar sendo que apenas tenho Strings de uma coluna de uma jtable que pode existir 1000 linhas

Sei que está vago pois não tenho um trecho de código fundamentado, porém não tenho a minima ideia de por onde posso começar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você começou bem, só se atrapalhou em manusear os dados eu acho..

> ```
> Tentei criar um conversor para mm:ss com SimpleDateFormat e armazenar as 
> informações em um vetor, onde apos isso tentaria somar as datas.
> ```

Volte nesse ponto da ideia e transformes as datas em long com Date.getTime() para realizar a media.

Algo como isto 
http://ideone.com/g49YRh

Comment: Irei testar, aparentemente é isso

Comment: Perfeito, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Algo que você pode fazer é o seguinte:

- Recupere os dados em forma de String.

Utilize este código para conseguir obter o número de minutos e de segundos em variáveis diferentes

```
String str = (String) q.getSingleResult();

int posicao = str.indexOf(':');
if (posicao >= 0) {
  int minutos = str.substring(0, posicao);
  int segundos = str.substring(1, posicao);
}
```

A partir daí, multiplique a quantidade de minutos por 60, e some com a quantidade de segundos para obter o total de segundos para aquela linha. Coloque esta parte do código dentro de um loop para que você faça esse cálculo para todas as linhas daquela coluna e no final divida pela quantidade de linhas na tabela, utilize a varíavel "i" para saber quantas linhas foram processadas.

Caso tenha alguma dúvida, comente aqui.